# Create SavedSearch Criteria Using OR not AND

Tags: finder, macos

I'd like to create a savedSearch in Finder that looks for recent Documents AND pdf's. If I create a rule such as:

```
Kind is Document
Kind is PDF
```

it will look for things that are Documents AND pdfs. How do I set it to look for Documents OR pdfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

1. Select Finder. Create a Smart Folder using the key combination <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
2. Click the `+` icon. `Kind is any` is the default search rule. Leave it for now.
3. **Most important step:** Hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key. You will see the `+` icon change to `…`
4. Simply click the `…` icon to add ***conditional criteria***. Use the default, `"Any : of the following are true”`
5. Specify the criteria using two rules: `Kind is Document` and `Kind is PDF`
6. Now, delete first search rule made in Step 2. Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

As you can see, “any of the following..” functions as “or” (versus “all of the following..” which functions as “and”)

Comment: This is so great! You can even combine "Any" and "All"!

Comment: @Adam_G Yes. And a TON more criteria to search by exist in the `…` dropdown than that which exist in the default dropdown. It’s a hidden feature that allows for one to search his filesystem in a much more powerful way! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since PDF is also a Document those can not be separated with a "or".

If you want to search only for pure Documents (non PDF) , the use the serch box and select what kind of document you are after

[image: document]

If you want to search for PDF (that are also Documents use that.